# Auto Increment While Building list in Python

Tags: python, list

Here is what I have so far.  Is there anyway, I can auto increment the list while it is being built?  So instead of having all ones, I'd have 1,2,3,4....

```
possible = []
possible = [1] * 100
print possible
```

Thanks,
Noah

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
possible = range(1, 101)
```

Note that the end point (101 in this case) is *not* part of the resulting list.

Comment: range doesn't return list in python3, so be aware.

Comment: it is, of course, trivial to create a list with `list(range(1,101))` in python3.x

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
start=1
count= 100
possible = [num for num in range(start,start+count)]
print possible
```